# Get more details about objects in debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, debugging

I have some issue about object in my project.
There is lots of objects in the view, and I wanna know the specific object with the issue.
The object ID is 0x7febf0ebcd20

How can I know more about this object?

Comment: Try enabling Zombie objects and puting an exception breakpoint

Answer (score -1):

> The object ID is 0x7febf0ebcd20
>   How can I know more about this object?

It depends on a few things. Usually you can improve the situation if you can build the component (like your program), but sometimes you can't (like using a pre-built library).

Make sure your project is set up to provide as much debugging information as possible. You can make the following changes on the ***Project***, and the various ***Targets*** will inherit from the project.

Ensure *`DEBUG=1`* is set under prerpocessor symbols. This usually affects Windows components more than Unix/Linux, but I've seen it used on cross-platform libraries.

[image]

Ensure *`-g3`* is sued in *`CFLAGS`*. `-g3` includes symbolic constants like `#define`. You can also set `-ggdb`, but it currently has no effect.

[image]

With debugging information available, you should be able to switch to the debugging terminal and issue `po 0x7febf0ebcd20` to print information about the object at the address.

Also see Apple's [Technical Note TN2239, iOS Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html) and [Technical Note TN2124, Mac OS X Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html).

Comment: Note, llvm doesn't do anything special with the -g3 flag, it is treated the same as -g.  It is supported as a flag for compatibility with gcc.  In particular, llvm does not generate DWARF macro debugging information when passed -g3.  In practice the macro debug information as currently designed bloats the debug information so much as to be unusable for a project that includes big system header trees (like Cocoa or UIKit), so neither llvm nor lldb support it.